# Как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от языка было перенаправление на ru или com?

Tags: .htaccess

Суть такая. Есть 2 домена, оба прикреплены к одному сайту, предположим, это домены domain.ru и domain.com.

Мне нужно, чтобы в зависимости от выбранного языка нас перекидывало на ru или com, т.е. чтобы, когда мы переходим на английскую версию (урл становится domain.ru/en), нас перебрасывало на domain.com/en.

И точно так же на англ. версии: когда мы заходим на domain.com/ru - нас перебрасывало на domain.ru/ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить c хтакессом так и не смог. сделал на пхп. Мб кому поможет.

```
$ss = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(substr_count($ss, 'domain.com/ru/')) {
    $url = "http://domain.ru/ru/";
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit();
}

if(substr_count($ss, 'domain.ru/en/')) {
    $url = "http://domain.com/en/";
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ru$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.ru/ru [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/en [L]
```